# Constructing User Journey - How do you 'self, loop' join?

Tags: python, sql

#### Sites

Let's say I have a website with pages such as i.e.:

1. Homepage
2. Page A
3. Page B
4. Page C
5. Checkout

#### User Journey Path

Hence, some viable user journey paths could possibly be:

- Homepage -> Page A -> Page B -> Page C -> Checkout
- Homepage -> Page A -> Page B

#### Current Schema

If my table **webPages** in SQL looks something like this

| userid | beforePage | afterPage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Homepage | Page A |
| 1 | Page A | Page B |
| 1 | Page B | Page C |
| 1 | Page C | Checkout |
| 2 | Homepage | Page A |
| 2 | Page A | Page B |

#### Question

How can I self-join with loop `afterPage` = `beforePage` such that I obtain something like this?

| userid | beforePage | afterPage | afterPage | afterPage | afterPage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Homepage | Page A | Page B | Page C | Checkout |
| 2 | Homepage | Page A | Page B |  |  |

or even:

| userid | pagesConcat |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [Homepage, Page A, Page B, Page C, Checkout] |
| 2 | [Homepage, Page A, Page B] |

Appreciate any methods there can be, i.e. using **SQL**, **Python**, etc. Thank you!

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using.  (2) Your results assume an ordering of the rows.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You should show the column that illustrates the ordering.

Comment: Add a tag for the database you are using . . . DB2, Oracle, Postgres, MySQL, SQL Server . . .

Answer (score 0):

Assign a sequential number and aggregate.  The one caveat is that you need a column that specifies the ordering:

```
select userid,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then beforepage end) as beforepage,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then afterpage end) as afterpage_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then afterpage end) as afterpage_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then afterpage end) as afterpage_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by <ordering col>) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by userid;
```

Comment: Thank you! Would there be an alternative to not require an ordering column? e.g. the web pages to traverse is unnecessarily 1 direction, i.e. Page A -> Page B -> Page A -> Homepage

Comment: @TonyNg . . . Following a linked list would troublesome because you could have loops.  And, how you do that depends on the database you are using which you haven't tagged.  There really should be an ordering column, such as a timestamp.

Comment: Ahh yes, timestamp can definitely be an ordering column. I will try this out. What does tagging database mean?